# What are the Old Gods up to?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

After killing Xavius in the Emerald Nightmare raid:

> the group is transported to Moon Glade in the Emerald Dream.

In this location is a cave where there is a flower that only Shadow Priests can interact with, when doing so Xal'Atath whispers the player with the following:

> "Almost completely gone, as if it never existed. But the Rift is deep and vast, somewhere down there it stirs. Something has changed, the last prison weakens. We must prepare."

Also while questing in Azshara it will again whisper the player with
this:

> "The Legion burrows deep here. If they burrow deeper, they may not like what they find."

Both of these lines appear to be hinting at some new developments with
the old gods.

I've heard of other things that Xal'Atath will say and know that other
artifacts will whisper the player as well.

Given that, what are all the lines in Legion that directly or indirectly talk
about the Old Gods?

Comment: not sure where to find all those quotes, but they probably point at N'Zoth...

Comment: Yes, I believe that is the case as well.

Comment: Unless someone else is already working on one, I'm going to start piecing an answer together over the weekend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my research while other weapons are sentient, Xal'Atath appears to be the only one that references the old gods.
However there are some quotes from within the Emerald Nightmare Raid that are relevant

### Quotes by Xal'Atath

The only clear cut references were those in the question, but there some others that based on my research appear to be related

#### Clear references

**While in Azuna**

> The Legion burrows deep here. If they burrow deeper, they may not like what they find.

**At the end of Emerald Nightmare**

> The God of the Deep writhes in his prison, breaking free ever so slowly. You should hurry and defeat the fallen titan... there are greater battles yet to fight.

#### Tenuous references

**While in Val'sharah**

> Here you will see why the Legion's invasion is ultimately futile. All
>  can be corrupted, dreams and demons alike.

Potentially hinting that maybe the Legion isn't our most pressing enemy.

**While in Stormheim**

> Do not be impressed by tall icons of the titans which stand here. The towers >! of sacrifice in Ny'alotha dwarf these pathetic temples

Mention of the sleeping city, more on this below.

#### While in Suramar

> This city of the elves pales in comparison to the sleeping city... (Near Suramar City)

Another mention of the sleeping city

#### Quotes by Il'gynoth

Most of these are not clear cut, don't really stand on their own as a reference, but with further investigation appear to be relevant.

**Randomly during encounter**

> Five keys to open our way. Five torches to light our path.

This is talking about the Pillars of Creation and potentially how they would be used to open the prison

> At the hour of her third death, she will usher in our coming.

This appears to refer to Sylvanas and that she may have something to do with opening the prison

> N’Zoth… I journey… to Ny’alotha…

Direct reference to the 'last' old god and to the sleeping city that may be the void version of the Twisting Nether

> The lord of ravens will turn the key.

Referring to someone who may be responsible for opening the prison.

In my research I came across [this brilliant post](http://warcraft.blizzplanet.com/blog/comments/terrible-truth-behind-pillars-creation-expansion-7) that speculates on a lot of the hidden meaning behind these quotes.

Conclusion: They're coming.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to format in the description lines after the spoiler blocked quotes, If anyone knows of a better way to do so please feel free to let me know or to edit.

Comment: There are several people who can be referred to as the Lord of Ravens: Kur'talos Ravencrest, who is the last boss in Black Rook Hold.  Medivh, who is plot important in Warcraft 1, Warcraft 3, and the Warcraft movie; additionally, Kharazhan (Medivh's tower) is reopening in 7.1.  Archmade Khadgar, who is the current wielder of Atiesh, Greatstaff of the Guardian (originally owned by Medivh).  Atiesh allows its wielder to assume the form of a Raven.